# How to make some generic programming in fortran 90/95 working with intrinsic types

Tags: fortran, fortran90, generic-programming, fortran95

I would like to program some procedure that will work with different types. I am planning to use the "include" method used in flibs described [here](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/linked_list.html) and [here](http://electroncollisions.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sqlite/flibs-0.9/flibs/tests/datastructures/two_lists.f90). I give here a simple exemple.

```
  ! -------------------------------------------------------------- ! 
  module data_type

  type ivalue
  integer :: v
  end type

  type rvalue
  real(8) :: v
  end type

  end module data_type
  ! -------------------------------------------------------------- ! 
  module imod

  use data_type, only: T => ivalue 

  include "template.f90"

  end module imod
  ! -------------------------------------------------------------- ! 
  module rmod

  use data_type, only: T => rvalue 

  include "template.f90"

  end module rmod
  ! -------------------------------------------------------------- ! 
  module mod

  use imod, only:
 &     ivalue => T,
 &     iprintme => printme

  use rmod, only:
 &     rvalue => T,
 &     rprintme => printme

  private
  public :: ivalue, rvalue
  public :: printme

  interface printme
  module procedure iprintme
  module procedure rprintme
  end interface printme

  end module mod
  ! -------------------------------------------------------------- !
  program hello

  use mod

  implicit none

  type(ivalue) :: iv
  type(rvalue) :: rv

  iv%v=42
  rv%v=3.14

  call printme(iv)
  call printme(rv)      

  end program hello
```

with the included file:

```
  contains

  subroutine printme(a)

  implicit none

  type(T) :: a

  print *,a

  end subroutine printme
```

What bothers me is that it seems only to work with derived type, and not with intrinsic types. If the user of the module mod want to use the printme routine on an simple integer, it is really annoying for him to encapsulate it in a ivalue type and cannot doing:

```
integer :: a=42
call printme(a)
```

Is there any way to extend this method to intrinsic types, or another method that would do it in strict f90/f95 (I don't want to use the "transfer" method because of the data copy)

Tanks!

Comment: Use the CPP preprocessor's #include, instead of the Fortran include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the C preprocessor (CPP) in all major Fortran compilers. Usually there is a flag for invoking it (`-cpp` in gfortran) or it is invoked automatically if the file suffix contains capital F (`.F90`, `.F`). The preprocessor allows more powerful inclusion of sources with the usage of macros.

```
module imod

  use data_type, only: ivalue 

#define T type(ivalue)
#include "template.f90"
#undef T

end module imod


module intmod

#define T integer
#include "template.f90"
#undef T

end module intmod
```

and template.f90

```
contains

subroutine printme(a)

  implicit none

  T :: a

  print *,a

end subroutine printme
```

This is not *strict* f90 / f95, but it uses a preprocessor, included in the compilers, which produces another (strict f95) source file and it automatically compiles it instead of the original source that contains the macros.

The compilation is then straightforward

```
gfortran -cpp main.f90
```

**--Edit--**

For non-believers, if you want to see some real code using this, check https://github.com/LadaF/fortran-list (disclaimer: my own code). You can use the parametric linked list there as:

list of len(20) character strings:

```
module str_list

#define TYPEPARAM character(20)

#include "list-inc-def.f90"
contains
#include "list-inc-proc.f90"
#undef TYPEPARAM
end module
```

list of integers

```
module int_list

#define TYPEPARAM integer

#include "list-inc-def.f90"
contains
#include "list-inc-proc.f90"
#undef TYPEPARAM
end module
```

list of some derived type

```
module new_type_list
  use, new_type_module, only: new_type

#define TYPEPARAM type(newtype)

#include "list-inc-def.f90"
contains
#include "list-inc-proc.f90"
#undef TYPEPARAM
end module
```

Comment: If ivalue is an intrinsic type, as per the question, you need F2008 for the resulting type declaration syntax.

Comment: No, really not, my compilers *do not* support this f2008 feature, which I am aware of quite well. See the difference, I use 'T ::' not, 'type(T) :: ', also, there is no renaming in use.

Comment: Ah true - I missed that in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit typing.  Make sure you wash your hands though - as this opens the possibility for the usual errors associated with implicit typing.

Consider a replacement for your module imod.

```
module imod
  use data_type    ! oops - I forgot this.
  implicit type(itype) (q)
contains
  include 'template.f90'
end module imod
```

(I've moved the contains statement into the including module - as it then allows you to have more than one templated include file.)

and then a procedure in included file that looks like:

```
 ! Assume anything starting with q is the type to be templated.
 subroutine printme(q_arg)
   print *, q_arg
 end subroutine printme
```

If you wanted to template printme for an intrinsic type, then you just change the implicit statement in the parent module appropriately.

---

It's debatable, but there's also the view that you can use the module renaming facility to introduce new names for intrinsic types.  If so, and if you have a F2008 compiler (so we aren't talking strict F95) then your current approach should still be able to work - using an intermediate module to allow renaming of the intrinsic integer type to have a name T.

But this confuses most (all?) compilers I've used in some way.  Given that, plus the debatable legality, plus it requiring F2008, it's not a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using Python to preprocess the Fortran source code. In the code that I'm working on, we use [this Python script](https://github.com/wyphan/exciting-plus-gpu/blob/openacc-summit/ftemplate.py) to preprocess the Fortran template. For instance, this is used to write interfaces for MPI functions, like this Fortran code snippet below:

```
module mod_mpi_grid
  implicit none

@python ftypes=["integer(2)","integer(4)","integer(8)","real(4)","real(8)","complex(4)","complex(8)","logical"]
@python fsuffixes=["_i2","_i4","_i8","_f","_d","_c","_z","_l"]
@python fsizeof=["2","4","8","4","8","8","16","2"]
@python fmpitypes=["MPI_INTEGER2","MPI_INTEGER","MPI_INTEGER8","MPI_REAL","MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION","MPI_COMPLEX","MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX","MPI_LOGICAL"]
@python ntypes=8

  interface mpi_grid_send
@template begin
@template variable fsuffix
@python for i in range(ntypes): fsuffix=fsuffixes[i];
    module procedure mpi_grid_send#fsuffix
@template end
  end interface

contains

:

@template begin
@template variable fsuffix
@template variable ftype
@template variable fmpitype
@python for i in range(ntypes): fsuffix=fsuffixes[i]; ftype=ftypes[i]; fmpitype=fmpitypes[i];
  subroutine mpi_grid_send#fsuffix(val,n,dims,dest,tag)
    use mpi
    implicit none

    ! arguments
    #ftype, intent(in) :: val
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: dims
    integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: dest
    integer, intent(in) :: tag

    ! local variables
    integer :: comm, dest_rank, req, ierr
    integer :: idims(0:ndmax)

    idims = convert_dims_to_internal(dims)
    comm = mpi_grid_get_comm_internal(idims)
    dest_rank = mpi_grid_rank_internal(comm,idims(0),dest)
    call mpi_isend(val,n,#fmpitype,dest_rank,tag,comm,req,ierr)

    return
  end subroutine mpi_grid_send#fsuffix
@template end

:

end module mod_mpi_grid
```

Then, at build time, the `Makefile` calls the following line to preprocess the template into a Fortran source code file for compilation:

```sh
python ftemplate.py < src/addons/mod_mpi_grid.tpl > src/addons/mod_mpi_grid.f90
```

All instances of `#ftype` in the subroutine are replaced by the intrinsic types `integer(2)`, `integer(4)`, ... `logical`. So, this approach works perfectly with intrinsic types!

The other parts of the code that need to send data over MPI would simply need to `use mod_mpi_grid` and the generic subroutine `call mpi_grid_send( ... )`.

Comment: And presumably one writes _another_ preprocessor step to populate the list of intrinsic kind parameters?

Comment: BTW, there is also  FYPP https://github.com/aradi/fypp  We ought to have an answer showing it, but I would prefer if it is written by someone who actually uses it.

Comment: @francescalus That's preprocessor inception!