# Fortran numeric class

Tags: class, fortran

In fortran I can use Class (*) in a subroutine and use

```
Select Type (ir)
Type Is (Integer (Int8)) 
Type Is (Integer (Int16)) 
End Select
```

Does there exist any way to pass a numeric value rather than using `Class (*)`, by using `Class (Integer)` for example or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Intrinsic types are not extended types, they have no common ancestor, nothing like that exist. You can use the unlimited polymorphism (`class(*)`) or you must indicate exact type and kind (`real(dp)`). You can also write `type(real)` in Fortran 2008, but that does not change anything, it is just a different syntax for the same.

Have a look at some common techniques for generic programming with different kinds like, for example, [How to make some generic programming in fortran 90/95 working with intrinsic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064633/how-to-make-some-generic-programming-in-fortran-90-95-working-with-intrinsic-typ) , [STL analogue in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979199/stl-analogue-in-fortran) and others. You normally make a separate procedure for each kind and paste the code body from an include file.