# Is it possible to do something similar to "typeclass" behaviour in Fortran?

Tags: generics, fortran, generalization

I am aware one can use an interface to create a single name for multiple functions. In fact, I've done so in a small code for something like that:

```
interface assert_equal
  procedure assert_equal_int
  procedure assert_equal_real
  procedure assert_equal_string
end interface
```

However, I noticed that most of the time I just need the first two dummy arguments of the function to implement some sort of equality. If I was trying to do this in Haskell, for instance, I would do something like

```
assertEqual :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> String -> IO ()
```

Where the first two arguments are the values being checked against each other and the third one is a message.

Or in Rust I would do, for instance

```
impl {
  fn assert_equal<T>(expected: T, actual: T, msg: &str) where T: std::Eq {
    ...
    # enter code here
  }
}
```

Is there something similar or that at least emulates the same behaviour in Fortran? The current issue I am trying to solve is being able to do some sort of `assert_equal` in derived types that I will create in my code base, without needing to define a specific subroutine for each derived type when they are going to look so similar

Comment: Would templating [approaches/hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23706742/3157076) work?

Comment: I suppose it is something, and I haven't really considered it. I think it would still imply creating a small stub for every derived type. And the main issue: I don't want the module to know about derived types.

I was looking at "pFUnit" for inspiration and that looks like straight up magic to me! I have no idea how the person who coded that manage to make `@assertEqual` work as I intend. It is like he created another language inside Fortran.

Comment: There is also an old technique with the `transfer` intrinsic to achieve generic programming in fortran: [see this link](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Generic+programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [fypp](https://fypp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can quite easily achieve such a behaviour:

```
#:def assert_equal(a, b, message="")
    if (any([${a}$ /= ${b}$])) then
        write(*, *) "assert_equal violated"
        write(*, *) ${a}$, '/=', ${b}$
#:if message
        write(*, *) ${message}$
#:endif
        error stop
    end if
#:enddef

program test_assert
    implicit none

    @:assert_equal(4, 4)
    @:assert_equal([3, 4], [3, 4])
    @:assert_equal(4., 4.)
    @:assert_equal("4", "4")

    @:assert_equal("4", "5", "this is my cool message")

end program
```

Which can be compiled via `fypp test_assert.fpp > test_assert.f90 && gfortran test_assert.f90`

Note that because we use `any([${a}$ /= ${b}$])` instead of `${a}$ /= ${b}$` it works for both scalar and array values, as long as a `/=` operation is defined.

Note that for most numerical codes I would actually not use an `assert_equal` like this:

1. Floating point numbers should be compared with some `|a - b| < epsilon` criterion.
2. The equality of large floating point arrays is better determined by equality under some matrix norm (e.g. Frobenius norm `sum((A - B)**2) < epsilon`) instead of just ensuring element wise equality.

For this reason I would rather recommend to only supply an `assert` macro.
Then developers will write something like:

```
@:assert(near_zero(sum((A - B)**2))))
```

when comparing two floating point arrays `A` and `B`.

PS: We use a similar approach in a largeish quantum chemistry program [here](https://github.com/ghb24/NECI_STABLE/blob/master/src/macros.fpph#L36C1-L36C1).

Comment: Why not try to do this with the, more common , C / C++ preprocessor (using `#define`)? Means also that you don't need to install Python for this.

Comment: Because there was never a standardized preprocessor for Fortran, hence implementations chose whatever they liked. Since `gcc` as one of the most important compilers supports only the Pre-ANSI C-preprocessor you will quickly hit a wall for anything that is more complicated than `#ifdef COMPILE_FLAG_`

Feel free to generate a working example that compiles with `gfortran` and its preprocessor.